# neo4j sorting nodes in java according to degree

Tags: java, sorting, neo4j

I need to sort nodes based on degree that are created by my program on the fly.

I tried to use Collections.sort() but it throws a null pointer exception. The **nodeList** parameter is list of nodes created by my program. I tried few different configurations, but it did not worked.

```
private  void sortNodes(List<Node> nodeList){

    Collections.sort(nodeList, new GraphModel());
}

public int compare(Node n1, Node n2) {

    int n1Degree,n2Degree;

    try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() ) {
        n1Degree = n1.getDegree();
        n2Degree = n2.getDegree();
        tx.success();

    }
    if(n1Degree<n2Degree){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(n1Degree==n2Degree){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Edit: I am adding relevant parts of the code.

```
public class GraphModel implements Comparator<Node> {

 GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
 List<Node> nodeList=new ArrayList<>();

 //constructor
 public GraphModel(String sentence, String MemoryName){

    Memory mem=new Memory();


    graphDb = new   GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(mem.getMemoryAddress(MemoryName));

  registerShutdownHook( graphDb );

  ....
  some more code here without any problem
  nodeList populated without any problem
  ....
  sortNodes(nodeList);

  } //end of constructor 
}
```

Node class is Node class of Neo4j.

Here is the stacktrace: Line 275 is "try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()" in compare method above.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at GraphModel.GraphModel.compare(GraphModel.java:275)
at GraphModel.GraphModel.compare(GraphModel.java:22)
at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:351)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:216)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
at GraphModel.GraphModel.highestDegreeNodes(GraphModel.java:137)
at GraphModel.GraphModel.<init>(GraphModel.java:130)
at com.company.Tester.main(Tester.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: What is the stack trace for your `NullPointerException`?  What line does it point to?

Comment: Also it would be helpful to see sample code of the GraphModel and Node classes.

Comment: According to your stacktrace, the exception occurs when your `highestDegreeNodes()` method [not `sortNodes()`] calls `Collections.sort()`. Please provide the code for `highestDegreeNodes()`. Also, the stacktrace seems to indicate that you have (at least) 2 different `compare()` methods -- they occupy lines 22 and 275. Please provide all compare methods as well, and indicate where lines 22 and 275 are.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not really thought through.

The sorting should occur within a TX and the sort method should really just be

```
public class NodeDegreeComparer implements Comparator<Node> {
  public int compare(Node n1, Node n2) {
    return Integer.compare(n1.getDegree(),n2.getDegree());
  }
}


  graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(PATH);
  registerShutdownHook( graphDb );

  try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
     Collections.sort(nodeList, new NodeDegreeComparer());
     tx.success();
  }
```